# CSS Border not showing

Tags: html, css

The question in the title, stumped with this and it's probably something simple?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<style>
#home_1 { width:920px; height:50px; float:left; border:1px solid black; }

.left_home1 { float: left; width: 33%; text-align: center; }

.mid_home1 { float: left; width: 34%; text-align: center; }

.right_home1 { float: left; width: 33%; text-align: center; }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="home1">

                <div class="left_home1">

                    left

                </div>

                <div class="mid_home1">

                    middle

                </div>

                <div class="right_home1">

                    right

                </div>

</div><!-- close home1 -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It should be `#home1` in the `style` tag.

Comment: thank you - sometimes you can be too far inside!

Comment: @SagarPatil: Why don't you say this in an answer, as it is actually _the_ answer...

Comment: @awe Wasn't much of an answer as much an observation.

Comment: @awe: Sometimes we aren't sure if it's a typo in the question or in the code (like Sagar said, it's just an observation), so we don't know for sure if it's actually *the* answer. That's why we have comments. The OP has self-answered though, so I'll just close this now.

Answer (score 1):

As correctly pointed out:

It should be #home1 in the style tag. – @Sagar Patil

My bad!

Answer (score 0):

Put `<br clear="all" />` before last `</div>`

Comment: The attribute has to be `clear` not `clean`

Comment: Also the value for the HTML `clear` attribute is `all`, not `both`.

Comment: @BoltClock: value for `clear` can be `both`

Comment: @Sunil Kumar B M: That's only for CSS `clear`, not HTML `clear`.

Comment: @BoltClock: ya correct!!

Answer (score 0):

In your css just change your css selector `#home_1` to `#home1`.It will work.